# load event is cauing my function to fire instead of a click event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a class to an element without javascript. I defined a function which will be fired when a button is clicked, but when i load the page, the class is added imediately using the onload event, instead of the specified clicked event. this is wierd,

```
<div id="div1" class="mydiv">A DIV</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click">

#div1 {
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
transition: top, left 0.43s 0.56s ease-in-out;
}
.move {
    top: 200px;
    left: 450px;
    transition: top, left 0,4s 0.58s ease-in-out;
}

function ulterClass (el, newClass) {
var currentClass = el.getAttribute('class');
if (typeof currentClass!== 'undefined' && currentClass) {
    el.setAttribute('class', currentClass + ' '+ newClass);
}else{
    el.setAttribute('class', newClass);
}
}
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
function ulterClass (el, newClass) {
var currentClass = el.getAttribute('class');
if (typeof currentClass!== 'undefined' && currentClass) {
    el.setAttribute('class', currentClass + ' '+ newClass);
}else{
    el.setAttribute('class', newClass);
}
}
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', ulterClass(div, 'move'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this statement. When it runs, it executes the function.

```
btn.onclick = ulterClass(div, 'move');
```

Instead you could assign the event handler using the `onclick` attribute on the button itself. Like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" onclick="ulterClass(div, 'move')">
```

```js
function ulterClass(el, newClass) {
  var currentClass = el.getAttribute('class');
  if (typeof currentClass !== 'undefined' && currentClass) {
    el.setAttribute('class', currentClass + ' ' + newClass);
  } else {
    el.setAttribute('class', newClass);
  }
}
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
// When this statement runs, it executes the function.
//btn.onclick = ulterClass(div, 'move');
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: top, left 0.43s 0.56s ease-in-out;
}

.move {
  top: 200px;
  left: 450px;
  transition: top, left 0, 4s 0.58s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="mydiv">A DIV</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" onclick="ulterClass(div, 'move')">
```

I would also suggest that instead of referring to global variable `div` in the event handler, you can provide its ID there. See this:

```js
function ulterClass(elementId, newClass) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var currentClass = el.getAttribute('class');
  if (typeof currentClass !== 'undefined' && currentClass) {
    el.setAttribute('class', currentClass + ' ' + newClass);
  } else {
    el.setAttribute('class', newClass);
  }
}
//var div = document.getElementById('div1');
//var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
// When this statement runs, it executes the function.
//btn.onclick = ulterClass(div, 'move');
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: top, left 0.43s 0.56s ease-in-out;
}

.move {
  top: 200px;
  left: 450px;
  transition: top, left 0, 4s 0.58s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="mydiv">A DIV</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" onclick="ulterClass('div1', 'move')">
```

Here's how you could do it with `addEventListener`:

```js
function ulterClass(el, newClass) {
  var currentClass = el.getAttribute('class');
  if (typeof currentClass !== 'undefined' && currentClass) {
    el.setAttribute('class', currentClass + ' ' + newClass);
  } else {
    el.setAttribute('class', newClass);
  }
}
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ulterClass(div, 'move');
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: top, left 0.43s 0.56s ease-in-out;
}

.move {
  top: 200px;
  left: 450px;
  transition: top, left 0, 4s 0.58s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="mydiv">A DIV</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" >
```

Comment: when i used the addEventListener, the function ran as soon as the page loaded.the function runs, even though i havent clicked the button, but it work just fine when the function is added inline via the html, attribute onclick

Comment: It wasn't because of `addEventListener`, it was again because of `ulterClass(div, 'move');`. I will update my answer to show how you could use addEventListener.

Comment: But can you please give me a small theory why i was getting it wrong? my function ulterClass() seems to run immediately the page loads,

Comment: That's because `addEventListener` expects a function. `function(){...}` is a function, but `functionName()` is not a function. So `functionName()` will be executed to see if it returns a valid function through `return` statement. If it did return a function , that returned function will be bound as an event listener.

Comment: thank you pal, you are indeed very helpful, please can you recommend a very good reading resources for me, that  will help improve my javascript coding.

Comment: You're welcome! You could learn from MDN or W3Schools, but I have mostly learned through experience.

Comment: yea guess experience is better, pal, can you message via my email, pedroyanky@gmail.com or maybe   a facebook contact will be just as fine.